# How to find out if an object/data is same type and contents of something in a list?

Tags: list, lua, roblox, conditional-operator

I wanna do something where you can find out if something is exact same type and contents as of a list. For example...

```lua
list = {1}
function("1", list) --Should return false
```

Another example...

```lua
list1 = {"1"}
function(1, list1) --Should return false
list2 = {1}
function(1, list2) --Should return true
```

This is on Roblox Studio.

I've tried to seek out to YouTube, but I didn't find an answer.

Comment: Do you want a shallow or a deep table comparison (how should we handle lists or other tables inside the list)?

Comment: something like this: 
```lua
list = {
929399199,
9390293992,
282818278,
717392284
}
```
(i want the game to only be accessible to some players so it'll be like 12 elements)

Comment: "I want the game to only be accessible to some players" - that use case sounds like you want to check whether a player is in a set/list of "whitelisted" players rather than comparing lists?

Comment: yeah, I put the userids of the whitelisted players in a list and check if `game.Players.Localplayer.UserId` is part of a list.

Comment: For that a list is the wrong data structure. I'd use a table with UserId's as keys and truthy values. Then you can simply do `whitelist[id]` to check whether a player is in the "set".

Answer (score 0):

You can use type() to compare.
Or simplier only for your case...

```
> list1 = {"1"}
> list2 = {1}
> testit = function(val, tab)
>> return(val == tab[1]) -- Check only first key
>> end
> testit(1, list1)
false
> testit(1, list2)
true
```

But with a little more code it is testing choosed numbered or named Key

```
testit = function(val, tab, pos)
  local pos = pos or 1 -- Key 1 is default
  return(val == tab[pos])
end
```

Impression

```
> list1['hello'] = 'world'
> testit('world', list1, 'hello')
true
> testit(1, list1)
false
> testit("1", list1)
true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function demo(arg,list)
for _, value in pairs(list) do
    if arg == value then
        return true
    end
end
return false
end
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**